# How do I plot the second coefficient (not including the intercept into a plot) can I choose which coefficient to draw with abline?

Tags: r, rstudio, economics

I am running a time series regression by doing:

```
ts(Regression.data, frequency = 12, start=c(2012,10))
```

and then running:

```
attach(Regression.data)
model <- lm(logsalesUK ~ time(Date) + Exchangerate)
plot(Exchangerate, logsalesUK)
```

I would like to return the regression line using:

```
abline(model)
```

However this returns the date regression line. Can someone explain to me how to choose the exchange rate regression line to the plot?

---bonus question---

Is this time series regression taking into account the seasonality specified in the `ts` function? (see above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the coefficients you need from `model` and feed them into `abline` explicitly:

```
abline(model$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]], model$coefficients[["Exchangerate"]])
```